# Prevent Google analytics from passing IP address to google optimize

Tags: google-analytics, google-optimize

I am installing Google Optimize for my client BUT they ask me how google optimize collects the data from the web. If I understood correctly, Google Optimize does not save any data. Instead, it uses data collected from Google Analytics. Is this correct?

If so, my client does not want Google Optimize to access the user IP address. I tried to create a view on google analytics but I don't know how to exclude the IP address field with a filter. Can I prevent Google analytics from passing IP address to Google Optimize?

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics does not show the IP address in the reports, you can still use the [anonymizeIp](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2763052?hl=en) parameter in order to obfuscate the last part of the IP and thus make it anonymous to the Google Analytics servers ([documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ip-anonymization)).